# Variable in trigger doesn't work for me

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create new trigger like this. But it gives me an error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER email_postid_truncate BEFORE INSERT
ON email_postid
BEGIN

SET @cnt = (SELECT count(*) FROM email_postid WHERE status='Remaining');
IF @cnt = 0 THEN

    --My query

END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger gives error like this

[image]
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `FOR EACH ROW` [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER email_postid_truncate BEFORE INSERT
ON email_postid
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
....
```

Comment: oops sorry. Thank u..:)